# Can I build Android apps with react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

The recently launched react native features just iOS app example and docs.

Comment: very good question. the "native" naming is very misleading at this point.

Comment: Good question! I was really hoping for android support from the start. The initial presentation seemed to hint at it.

Comment: Android support after 6 months of React Native release. Marketing savvy Facebook is playing well.

Comment: Yeah. I'd recommend using Android Studio as your environment. Its installation can be a little tricky, but if you follow a good tutorial you'll get through it alright. Once its installed, you might be surprised at how easy building Android apps can be with React-Native as opposed to Obj C or Swift.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Yes.

React Native for Android was released September 14th, 2015.

Docs: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Comment: Works great! But as of Nov. 20, 2015, it still requires lots of debugging, pull requests, and willingness to ride the bleeding edge. See: [Known issues](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#missing-modules-and-native-views)

Answer (score 52):

<strike>No. You can't build Android apps with this release.</strike>

Facebook has indicated that they are working on an Android version, and famously said "give us 6 months", which [some people have taken as a promise](http://www.reactnativeandroid.com).  I wouldn't base any important business decisions on the illusion that it will be unveiled when the 6 months is over, but you can at least take some hope in the fact that they're serious about making it production-ready before they give us access to it, and that it's not just a pie-in-the-sky hope.

Also, as others have pointed out, Facebook has already release apps that they've built with the Android version of React Native.  So at least *parts* of it are ready for prime time.

**UPDATE**

Early support for React Native for Android has been pushed to GitHub!

As noted, there are several things that are currently not working if trying to port an application from iOS. But it's worth checking out.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/42eb5464fd8a65ed84b799de5d4dc225349449be

Comment: Why the down-vote? Did I miss something in this release?

Comment: Dunno. Came here because of NAA flags, which is even more puzzling.

Comment: Did you find out some statement from facebook on the matter?

Comment: OK, apparently it's stated as 'coming soon': https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/271

Comment: @JustinNiessner: Probably because your answer is more like a comment. Even though it is technically an answer.

Comment: "Can I build Android apps with react native?" "No. You can't build Android apps with this release." Seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: Because people don't like the answer. It's a true answer, and perfectly valid. People just don't like it. :(

Comment: My upvote will counter-act the gratuitous down-vote (well only one of them, if there were more) but most people expect a little more detail in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

It is not aiming to be a cross platform, write-once run-anywhere, tool. It is aiming to be learn-once write-anywhere. -Colin Eberhardt, from Raywenderlich

Good news is that React Native for Android is finally here. (https://code.facebook.com/posts/1189117404435352)

Comment: But considering it's all based on the same language, couldn't a major part of it (application logic) be shared between platforms, leaving only the UI to need custom code?

Answer (score 6):

while you can't do it right now, it shouldn't take that long.

The first React Native Android App has been published about two weeks ago in the play store as tweeted by the reactjs twitter account:

https://twitter.com/reactjs/status/615638361328349185

Answer (score 2):

Great news! Now its possible!

"And so it happens, the commit we're waiting since about 6 months!" - usereact.com

Please read more on: http://www.reactnative.com/react-native-for-android/

Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNNR01NF290

[image: Glad]

Comment: not to break the big smile, but if you are using a pc you have to wait (`windows` and `linux` not  officialy supported)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried out Facebook react native on Android and it really worked.

Simple Ubuntu install guide can be found [here](http://goo.gl/CyXp2G)

Simple js files: [link](https://goo.gl/KhBWud)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , We can now developed android apps too in react-native.

and some of the apps are already developed in react-native for android 
suchs as:

### 1)F8

### 2)Facebook ads manager

### 3)Squad

### 4)Discovery VR

### 5)Ziliun etc..

and many more still counting.

Developers from around the world now opting react-native for mobile app development because of easy of use of JSX syntax.

and also it is commonly noted as simply the V in MVC.
Since React makes no assumptions about the rest of your technology stack, it's easily embeddable within an existing non-React Native app.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR; Yes,**

**Detailed answer** (As of November 2017)

React Native android application development is very stable and a good number of Android applications have been already built and used in production using React-Native.

You can find a showcase of applications [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html). Most of them have both IOS and Android versions.

You can also easily integrate your native Android java code to react-native. Refer [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)

As a developer who is building Android app using react-native with a lot of native java code dependencies, react-native runs stable and I found the documentation and community support is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works for both the platforms ios and android, be sure to mention code entry points in app.js if it uses different code for different platforms. However native functions like native events or location manager need to be coded in native languages and then exported using RCT_EXPORT, you can find more about it in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Sure,
     Using React Native you can build real mobile app. real app means close to platform or simply can say 99% native app.react native provide easy way for building native android app using javascript for lucrative design.You have basic knowledge of android studio and error fixing in android studio related native module integration and good understanding of react.js then you can build android app using react native.
**Basic Requirement for android app** 
1. Configure android studio please follow below link and avoid installation of python.
 https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started .
2. for UI you will learn flex-box from official documentation.
I thing that is enough

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not just with android but also with iOS using XCode

Comment: That is not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make real-world mob application with React-Native. React-Native is used to create a hybrid mobile application. In this, we write code in javascript which gets converted to swift for ios and java for android.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can build the Android app using React Native. For this, you have to install Android Studio with all the required SDKs. You can run your React Native app in Android simulator by using Android Studio and command line both.

For command line, run the following command:

```
react-native run-android
```

Otherwise you can open the android project in Android Studio which is created by React Native in android folder and run the project from there.

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely build android apps using react-native.This is one of the great benefits of React Native. Before Facebook created it, you had to build your app twice and with different code : one for iOS using Swift or Objective-C and one for Android using Java or Kotlin.